# Nothing happens when trying to add/set default gateway

Tags: ip, routing, openvpn

I'm connected to a network using VPN (Managed byt NetworkManager, Fedora 23), and I want to route all traffica via the VPN network. But for some reason nothing happens when I  run `ip route add` or `ip route default`

```
root@laptop:~ $ ip route 
default via 192.168.144.1 dev wlp68s0b1  proto static  metric 600 
10.135.0.0/16 dev tap0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.135.100.16  metric 50 
192.168.144.0/24 dev wlp68s0b1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.144.136  metric 600
```

And wen running  `ip route replace`:

```
root@laptop:~ $ ip route replace default via 10.135.0.2 dev tap0
root@laptop:~ $ ip route 
default via 192.168.144.1 dev wlp68s0b1  proto static  metric 600 
10.135.0.0/16 dev tap0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.135.100.16  metric 50 
192.168.144.0/24 dev wlp68s0b1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.144.136  metric 600
```

Same thing when running `ip route add`

```
root@laptop:~ $ ip route add default via 10.135.0.2 dev tap0
root@laptop:~ $ ip route 
default via 192.168.144.1 dev wlp68s0b1  proto static  metric 600 
10.135.0.0/16 dev tap0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.135.100.16  metric 50 
192.168.144.0/24 dev wlp68s0b1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.144.136  metric 600
```

The default gateway is not updated, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to replace the default gateway is

```
 ip route del default via 192.168.144.1 
 ip route add default via x.y.w.z dev $DEV
```

The reason why I did not include the values you would like to see (10.135.0.2 and `tap0`) in the previous command is that this is not the correct way to force all traffic thru the VPN. However, you cannot have a correct routing table because you have not bridged the virtual interface with the ethernet NIC. Normally, this is done automatically, thus the lack of a proper bridge indicates that you are missing some component.

Perhaps, you are missing the `bridge-utils` package. But there is also another possibility, that you have created the wrong virtual interface. `tap0` is not supposed to receive an IP address, but `tun0` is. `tap0` must be inserted into a bridge, and it is the new bridge, `br0` which receives the IP address.  `tun0` does receive an IP address, but it does not require being inserted into a bridge.

So, which one do you need? It depends on your server. Which kind of VPN are you tring to connect to? OpenVPN? And if so, is that a `routed` or `bridged` VPN? Once you have answered these questions, I might be able to help you more.

Comment: I'm connected to an OpenVPN. OK, so there is some kind of silent failure happening then? By experience I've seen that bridging is not set up correctly by NetworkManager. Perhaps that could be part of the problem.I've reconfigured network manager to expose a `tun` interface instead (but I see a lot of errors regarding "Invalid argument" in the syslog). How would I go about manually bridging? I don't seem to be able to add tun0 to bridge

Comment: @Kotte You cannot bridge a tun interface. Please read here, http://superuser.com/questions/818347/how-to-bridge-tap-to-eth0-on-raspberry-pi/818460#818460